# How to get all results by iterating through has_more

Tags: python-3.x, loops, stackexchange-api

I am using stackexchange api to get comments from 2000 to 2019 August. It looks like I only iterate through 2 pages. I am not sure whether my mistake is in the api parameters or in the iteration process.

This is my code looks like.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import json
import csv
import os
import pprint

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

def write_to_json(data):
    curr_dir = os.getcwd()
    output_file_path = os.path.join(curr_dir, 'so_comment1.json')

    with open(output_file_path, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)

def get_comments(fromdate, todate):


    so_url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments?site=stackoverflow&filter=!1zSn*g7xPU9g6(VDTS7_c&fromdate=' \
        +str(fromdate)+'&todate='+str(todate)+'&pagesize=100'
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}

    resp = requests.get(so_url, headers = headers)

    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print('error: ' + str(resp.status_code))
    else:
        print('Success')

    data = resp.json()
    data1 = resp.json()
    page_num = 1
    if data1['has_more']:
        page_num += 1
        so_url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments?site=stackoverflow&filter=!1zSn*g7xPU9g6(VDTS7_c&fromdate=' \
            +str(fromdate)+'&todate='+str(todate)+'&pagesize=100&page='+str(page_num)

        resp = requests.get(so_url, headers = headers)

        if resp.status_code != 200:
            print('error: ' + str(resp.status_code))
        else:
            print('Success')

        data1 = resp.json()

        for item in data1['items']:
            data['items'].append(item)

    write_to_json(data)       

def filter_comment_body():
    with open('so_comment1.json') as json_file_so:
        comments = json.load(json_file_so)

        with open('comments1.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as comments_file:
            comments_writer = csv.writer(comments_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

            for item in comments['items']:
                comments_writer.writerow([item['body']])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # once comments are written to json file(s) stop calling to get_comments
    fromdate = datetime.strptime('Jan 1 2000', '%b %d %Y')
    todate = datetime.strptime('Aug 1 2019', '%b %d %Y')
    # print(datetime.timestamp(fromdate), ' ', datetime.timestamp(todate))
    get_comments(fromdate, todate)
    filter_comment_body()
```

Considering the date range I assume that I will get 1000s of comments. 
But I only received 200 comments (2 pages)

Comment: you should add some code to save a copy of `resp` to a file each time iteration.  also for `data1`.  that might help you know where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for two pages - and you received two pages.

1. You get the first page
2. ...and set `page_num = 1` after that
3. Then you check if `data1['has_more']`

   1. If this is the case, you increment `page_num`, download the second page and return from `get_comments`.
   2. If it's not, the code just returns

Is that what you intended to do? I think you meant to continue downloading new pages until `data1['has_more']` becomes `False`.

So, the algorithm may go like this:

```
create an empty list where you want to hold the data
set page_num=1

begin_loop:
    download page number page_num
    if data['has_more'] is False:
        goto return_from_function

    append the elements from `data` to the list you created earlier
    increment page_num
    goto begin_loop

return_from_function:
    process the data in the list created on step 1 and return
```

Comment: Silly me. Instead of a loop I placed a conditional statement. Thanks pointing that out.